# Is there a TempData equivalent in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I want to maintain state across a redirect and want to maintain some state across the redirect. TempData in MVC does this and flash messages in rails i think. ANy equivalent feature in ServiceStack. I wanted to check with the community before rigging something up myself.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good use case for [sessions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions).

```
// In your AppHost...
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());
}
```

You can then create a custom class that will hold your session data:

```
public class CustomSession : AuthUserSession {
    public string CustomId { get; set; }
}
```

You can access it in your services as such:

```
public class MyService : Service {
    public object Get(MyRequest req) {
        SessionAs<CustomSession>().CustomId = "Hello World"; // Save a value
    }
    public object Get(MyOtherRequest req) {
        var customId = SessionAs<CustomSession>().CustomId; // Read
    }
}
```